# How to solve the error information in numerical integration and solve Sp?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

**How to solve the error information in numerical integration and solve `Sp`?**

The codes are as follows:

```
Z = 1.0; l = 0.0; R0 = 10;
ff = Hypergeometric1F1[l + 1 - \[Beta], 2 l + 2, (2 Z R0)/\[Beta]];
\[Beta]0 = \[Beta] /. FindRoot[ff, {\[Beta], 1}];
Rnl[r_] := 
  Hypergeometric1F1[l + 1 - \[Beta]0, 2 l + 2, (
    2 Z r)/\[Beta]0] Exp[(-2 Z r)/(2 \[Beta]0)] ( (2 Z r)/\[Beta]0)^l;
Rnlh[p_] := 1/p Sqrt[2/Pi] Integrate[r Rnl[r] Sin[p r], {r, 0, R0}];
norm = Sqrt[Integrate[(Rnlh[p]^2) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]];
Rnlend[p_] := Rnlh[p]/norm;
fpp[p_] := 1/Pi Abs[Rnlend[p]]^2;
```

After loading the above functions, my final goal is to solve **`Sp`**.

```
Sp = -4 Pi NIntegrate[fpp[p] Log[fpp[p]] p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}]
```

In the process of solving **`Sp`**, the program will run for a long time and report an error. So I verify **`fpp[p]`**.

When entering 0.001.

```
N@fpp[0.001]
```

However, the error message in the obtained result shows that it is not a numerical value.

```
0.802354/Abs[NIntegrate[(2 (\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(10\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-0.9999\)\ r\)]\ r\ \
Hypergeometric1F1[\(-7.367*^-7\), 2. , 2. \ r]\ Sin[
           p\ r] \[DifferentialD]r\)\))^2)/\[Pi], {p, 
    0, \[Infinity]}]]
```

When entering Infinity.

```
N@fpp[Infinity]
```

The result is 0.

```
0
```

To sum up, I want to know how to solve this error and solve **`Sp`**.Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) to [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Z = 1; l = 0; R0 = 10;
ff = Hypergeometric1F1[l + 1 - β, 2 l + 2, (2 Z R0)/β];
β0 = β /. FindRoot[ff, {β, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 15];

Rnl[r_] = Hypergeometric1F1[l + 1 - β0, 2 l + 2, 
     (2 Z r)/β0] Exp[(-2 Z r)/(2 β0)] ((2 Z r)/β0)^l;

Rnlh[p_?NumericQ] := 
 1/p Sqrt[2/Pi] NIntegrate[r Rnl[r] Sin[p r], {r, 0, R0}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 15]

norm = Sqrt[
   NIntegrate[(Rnlh[p]^2) p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 15]];

Rnlend[p_?NumericQ] := Rnlh[p]/norm;

fpp[p_?NumericQ] := 1/Pi Abs[Rnlend[p]]^2;

Sp = -4 Pi NIntegrate[fpp[p] Log[fpp[p]] p^2, {p, 0, Infinity}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* 4.14256890106257 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a good answer.